# Looking for a formula using the table below to bring in the correct credit value based on what the discount value and the product is

Tags: excel-formula

Looking for a formula using the table below to bring in the correct credit value based on what the discount value and the product is. For example I know for books with discountt value of .57 the credit (based on the table) should be 66.67% but how can I achieve it through formula? Any help would be greatly appreciate. Thank you!

[image]

After using the formula from @Scotts Answer:

[image]

Comment: I rolled back to the previous edit, as it seemed you added 2 instances of the same screenshot.

Comment: Are the Mins broken out the same for all the products?

Comment: Thanks BigBen! can you please help with this questions?

Comment: Scott Craner..yes the Mins are broken out the same way for all products but the credits vary depending on the product. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX with two MATCHES in the second criterion:

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH("Supplies",A:A,0)+MATCH(.57,$B$2:$B$8)-1)
```

This first finds the first instance of `Supplies` in Column A and returns that row number.  Then it adds where it finds `.57` in the first Min break down relatively then subtracts one.

So for this it finds `Supplies` in row `9` then it finds where `.57` hits in the 3 cell in `$B$2:$B$8`.  So the math is `9+3-1` which is `11` which would return row 11 in column D.

Comment: Thanks Scott Craner. Is there a reason why this formula work at some times but not at others? Please see below. Not sure if I missed something.

Comment: I just added a picture to the original ask to show what I tried doing. thanks

Comment: It is because you change `$B$2:$B$8` to the full column, don't change it.  it needs to refer to the first break down of the minimum percentages.

Comment: please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.